# how can i make a grid container be in full size of a page?

Tags: html, css

Learning grid display and can't figure out how to make grid full size of a page. for example:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  border-style: solid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
grid-template-areas:
  'a a a'
  'a a a'
  'b b b';
}

.first {
  background-color: grey;
  grid-area: a;
}

.second {
  grid-area: b;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Oil Tycoon</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="first">
    123
  </div>
  <div class="second">
  123456
  </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

here's three columns that picked by two element but they are not in a full size of a screen as should grid-template-area do. how do i make grid fullscreen?

Comment: Check google for "reset css sheets"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The body will only stretch as far as there will be content to fill the space. Therefor you should give both the grid and the body a min-height of 100vh. vh means "viewport height".

```
body, wrapper {min-height; 100vh;}
```

You can play with the solution on Codepen: https://codepen.io/jensgro/pen/bGLyXVy?editors=1100

Cheers, Jens

Comment: ah i misread the question lol oops

Comment: this will still overflow because of the default body margin. Also you onyl need to give the grid-container a min-height.

Comment: @tacoshy  The grid container has a min-height, as I wrote body and wrapper in one rule. And of course, any padding and margin on the body should be set on 0. I forgot to mention this. Maybe, because I usually use normalize (like in my Codepen).

Comment: then edit your answer accordingly. Also do not link to codepens. Use the stacksnippet ('ctrl+M` or `<>`-button) to show code that can be run directly on this site without relaying on external resources.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to browsers having built in margin or padding. Take a look at [Normalize](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) which resets browsers default styling behaviour.

I have added

```css
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; min-height:100vh;}
```

This removes margin and padding from the body resetting its default styles., you can then add you own margin to your elements.

```css
body {
  margin: 0; padding:0; min-height:100vh;
}

.wrapper {
  min-height:100vh
  display: grid;
  border-style: solid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
grid-template-areas:
  'a a a'
  'a a a'
  'b b b';
}

.first {
  background-color: grey;
  grid-area: a;
}

.second {
  grid-area: b;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Oil Tycoon</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="first">
    123
  </div>
  <div class="second">
  123456
  </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: normalize did helped me not. only removed gaps, but made fullscreen not

Comment: I didn't mention to use Normalize it was just for reading. You will need to remove margin and padding from your body first. Like my answer, if you run my code example you can see it's full screen.

Comment: im sorry but for me it's still not in fullscreen. using chromium. either on your spinnet either on my code where i removed margin and padding

Comment: you dont ened to reset the padding, only the margin. Your code doesnt work because you miss a semicolon after the 100vh!